В Intellij IDEA в горячих клавишах не работает кнопка alt. Windows 11
Все комбинации горячих клавиш, где присутствует кнопка alt - не работают. Проблема наблюдается как в комьюнити версии, так и в ультимэйт. Даже не знаю, в какую сторону копать, гугл по этому поводу молчит. Может кто сталкивался? Или есть какие предположения? Windows стоит 11, оригинальный образ с офф сайта, с левой активацией.

 кмс


может у вас keymap в ij не windows?
